# debug_backtrace: browser doesn't respond/hangs

Tags: php, debugging

I'm trying to see how many times a file is included. Someone recommended me to replace the code of the file with this:

```
<pre>
<?php
    var_dump(debug_backtrace());

?>
</pre>
<hr />
```

but the browser just show the first page of the output and then doesn't respond so I can not scroll the view.

Any idea?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting header to text/plain.

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

This will help browser to render the page assuming that you are loading a lot of data.

Alternatively, you should/could use `require_once` and avoid the worry, assuming that you include file similar to `bootstrap` or helper functions pack.

Depending on how big the script is and how much recursion there is (if any) `debug_backtrace()` can be very long.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble, nothing seemed to fix it so I used the `print` version:

```
ob_start();
debug_print_backtrace();
$bt = ob_get_clean();
```

not elegant, but the hanging problem disappeared.